# swiper slider is not resposive on mobile

Tags: html, css, slider, responsive, swiper.js

Im using this Slider from [swiper.js](https://swiperjs.com/) but its not responsive on mobile using safari or firefox. its working fine on chrome for some users but no everyone.
here [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Hbm.jpg) of how it looks like on mobile.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        spaceBetween: 30,
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
            el: ".swiper-pagination",
            clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
    });
```

```css
.swiper {
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-rtl .swiper-button-next {
    color: #ffffff; !important
}

.swiper-container{
    width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<section class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper mySwiper">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="*"  alt="*">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        @endfor
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
```